# how to do this without "match ... with"

Tags: spring

For a better understanding, I try to rewrite this code without "... with" but I struggle:

```
let rec blast list =
    list with
        | x :: y :: [] -> x
        | hd :: tl -> blast tl
        | _ -> fail "not enough";;
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What does your attempt look like? What are you struggling with, specifically?

Comment: Are you allowed the use the functionality in the List module? You really didn't qualify what's allowed.

Comment: @G4143 yes for list.hd or list.tl but i'd like to avoid list.length for example to deconstruct and understand a maximum.

Comment: It's really not pretty. Whoever asked for this, tell them that that's not how OCaml is supposed to be used 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure we could "manually" try to match each pattern.

The first applies when there is exactly 2 elements, the second when there is more than 1 (but not 2) and the third in all other cases (0 elements).

The second case can be folded into the last case (As when there is 1 element, the recursive call just fails).

So now we have 3 cases: exactly 2, more than 2 and less than 2.

Perfect for `List.compare_length_with: 'a list -> int -> int`:

```ml
let rec beforelast list =
  let cmp = List.compare_length_with list 2 in
  if cmp = 0 then  (* Exactly 2 elements *)
    List.hd list
  else if cmp > 0 then  (* More than 2 elements *)
    beforelast (List.tl list)
  else  (* 1 or 0 elements *)
    failwith "not enough"
```

Though note that you are still pattern matching under the hood, because that's what OCaml data types are made for. For example, `List.hd` might be implemented like:

```ml
let hd = function
| head :: _ -> head
| [] -> raise (Failure "hd")
```

So the `match ... with` way should be the way that leads to a better understanding.

Comment: It's very clear, thank you very much for your time. I have a better understanding. It works very well but in an online compiler I have `Error: Unbound value List.compare_length_with`

Comment: @tartopo1 List.compare_length_with was added in the 4.05.0 version of the compiler. The online version probably runs an older version.